# Interrupts not working on MSP430 when using different PWM pin

Tags: msp430

I have a very strange issue I have been stuck on for a few hours now and no matter how often I read and re-read the datasheet and user guide, I still cannot work it out.

I am using an [MSP430FR6927](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6927) and I need to generate a PWM signal, and I am also using interrupts on I/O pin P3.0.

When I use pin P1.6 for my PWM, using timer TA0 (as per datasheet), everything works fine. When the interrupt on P3.0 is seen, my interrupt handler kicks in, does what it needs to do and everything is fine.

Due to PCB layout, things would be easier if I could use P1.7 to generate the PWM signal, so I have switched over to P1.7, and the PWM signal generates fine, but the interrupts do not trigger on P3.0 any more.

These are the lines of code that have been changed:

```
#define Enable_PWM              P1SEL1 |= 0b01000000 , P1SEL0 |= 0b01000000   // Set P1.6 to PWM
#define Disable_PWM             P1SEL1 &=~ 0b01000000 , P1SEL0 &=~ 0b01000000 // Turn the PWM off
```

Was changed to:

```
#define Enable_PWM              P1SEL1 |= 0b10000000 , P1SEL0 |= 0b10000000   // Set P1.7 to PWM
#define Disable_PWM             P1SEL1 &=~ 0b10000000 , P1SEL0 &=~ 0b10000000 // Turn the PWM off
```

And

```
void Turn_On_PWM(void)
{
  Enable_PWM;
  TA0CCR0 = 32-1;
  TA0CCTL1 = OUTMOD_7;       // Reset/Set
  TA0CCR1 = 16;
  TA0CTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_1;  // ACLK, UP mode
}
```

Has been changed to:

```
void Turn_On_PWM(void)
{
  Enable_PWM;
  TA0CCR0 = 32-1;
  TA0CCTL2 = OUTMOD_7;       // Reset/Set
  TA0CCR2 = 16;
  TA0CTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_1;  // ACLK, UP mode
}
```

Just these little changes means my interrupt no longer generates on the I/O pin P3.0. The only real difference I can see is that changing the output to P1.7 uses the TA2 module as the output, but I changed my other timers so that TA2 is no longer used for anything else (to avoid potential clashes) and this still didn't fix the issue.

I have looked through the documentation a lot and it is all starting to blur now! If anyone has any idea what is going on, I would be very grateful for the help. If this is more suited to Stack Overflow, then please let me know and I'll move it over there.

Comment: The code that you have shown does not configure or read P3.0.

Comment: @CL. no, because that part hasn't been changed. I only showed the parts of the code that had been changed. The interrupt on P3.0 has been set up and works correctly when P1.6 is configured as the PWM output. The code snippets in the questions are just the parts that were edited to change to P1.7 for PWM, then the interrupt stops working